# ValueError: unconverted data remains: 00:00:00

Tags: python, odoo

I have problem in convert date time.

Here is my code:

```
@api.multi
def action_confirm(self):
if picking.state not in ['cancel', 'draft']:
    for schedule_delivery in sorted_key:

    print "line 105: ", schedule_delivery
                dup_picking = picking.copy()
                        if shift == "afternoon":
                            date_object = datetime.strptime(schedule_delivery, '%Y-%m-%d')
                            print "Line 146", date_object
                            # raise EnvironmentError
                            tanggal = datetime.strftime(date_object, "%Y-%m-%d") + ' 06:00:00'
                            print "Line 145", tanggal
                            dup_picking.min_date = tanggal
                        else:
                            dup_picking.min_date = schedule_delivery
```

Error:

```
    date_object = datetime.strptime(schedule_delivery, '%Y-%m-%d')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  00:00:00
```

Comment: You could do this, datetime.strptime(str(schedule_delivery), '%Y-%m-%d ')

Answer (score 10):

You can use this line of code-

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(str(schedule_delivery), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 2):

i know its was asked a long time ago, i hope its still relevant.

in order to avoid the remains of the time format you need to convert your datetime to date

this is the code that solved this issue for me:

> 

self.start_date=str((datetime.strptime(str(self.start_date), '%Y-%m-%d')+timedelta(nDays))**.date()**)

> Blockquote

Answer (score -2):

Change the date to a pandas date:

Time object e.g

```
a = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda x: x.date())
```

Then

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(str(schedule_delivery), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: pandas is overkill to deal with simple stuff like this